# Understanding elements of list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to count lines of each element of a list. The list has 15 elements 0-14, and each has 1 to 5 lines of 20 characters per line. This works when not a list but a single file.

```
for j in range(0, 15): 
    with open('slash', 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read()
        news_line = data.splitlines()
print(textwrap.fill(news_line[2], 20))
n = len(news_line[2])
    print n
```

Comment: If you have a list, `lst`, you can do `len(lst)` to retrieve the number of elements in that list. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. The elements are always 15. I want to count the rows or lines in each element. They could be 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, the first two lines get the content of the file as one big string; the third line splits that string into a list os individual string, one for each line.

In your problem, you have a list of elements where each element is like the string from the file (as best I can tell from your description).  Thus, you need to mimic what the posted code does, but for every element of the list, and add those together.

Comment: Right now, 'news' is a 4 row file of 20 characters per row. Thus n = 4. Next I want to use a list instead of 15 elements, counting rows of each element. I think I can't count rows in a list, only characters.

Comment: As I said, you can count rows in each *element* of a list individually, then add up those individual counts.

Comment: I don't want to add the rows together. 'n' will be an index with more code for a display so display does not over write.

Comment: Then instead of getting `data` from a file, get it from the desired element of the list, and use `splitlines` and `len` as in your posted code.

Comment: for j in range(0, 15):
    with open('slash', 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read()
        news_line = data.splitlines()
print(textwrap.fill(news_line[2], 20))
n = len(news_line[2])
print n

Comment: The full code at top gives 4 rows at 20 characters per row, but 'n' shows to be 66, not 4, like it would be not using a list, but a single file.

Comment: New code *still* reads the same file 15 times (or would if it was indented properly).